# Populate dropdown from 2 dimensional array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following dropdown slect:

```
<select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();"></select>
```

I need to populate this with values I get from a Javascrippt array of this type:

```
{"name":"Hotel1","address":"Bondi Beach","lat":"6.369869","lng":"80.042055","thumb_path":"img\/hotel1.jpg"},{"name":"Hotel2","address":"Coogee Beach","lat":"6.025822","lng":"80.305727","thumb_path":"img\/hotel2.jpg"},{"name":"Hotel3","address":"Cronulla Beach","lat":"6.691994","lng":"79.928771","thumb_path":"img\/hotel3.jpg"},{"name":"Hotel4","address":"Manly Beach","lat":"6.887130","lng":"80.093420","thumb_path":"img\/hotel4.jpg"},{"name":"Hotel5","address":"Maroubra Beach","lat":"7.362609","lng":"79.825005","thumb_path":"img\/hotel5.jpg"}
```

I tried the following, but it doesnt work.

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    $('#start select').append('<option value=' + locations[i]['name'] + '>' + locations[i]['name'] + '</option>');
    alert("sdgsfg");
}
```

Please suggest a fix.

Comment: **1.** Selector is wrong, use `$('#start')` **2.** The `value` of the options should be wrapped in quotes

Comment: thanks that fixed it.

Comment: iterating over properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: @PieterWillaert OP is iterating over array of objects, so `for` is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `$('#start select')` will select the `<select>` element inside the `#start` element which not work as the id of the `select` itself is `start`. To select the element correctly use

```
$('#start') // or $('select#start')
```

It's better not to mess with HTML strings. You could use Option constructor to create new option element.

```js
var locations = [{"name":"Hotel1","address":"Bondi Beach","lat":"6.369869","lng":"80.042055","thumb_path":"img\/hotel1.jpg"},{"name":"Hotel2","address":"Coogee Beach","lat":"6.025822","lng":"80.305727","thumb_path":"img\/hotel2.jpg"},{"name":"Hotel3","address":"Cronulla Beach","lat":"6.691994","lng":"79.928771","thumb_path":"img\/hotel3.jpg"},{"name":"Hotel4","address":"Manly Beach","lat":"6.887130","lng":"80.093420","thumb_path":"img\/hotel4.jpg"},{"name":"Hotel5","address":"Maroubra Beach","lat":"7.362609","lng":"79.825005","thumb_path":"img\/hotel5.jpg"}]

var select = $('#start')[0];
locations.forEach(function(location) {
    select.add(new Option(location.name, location.name));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="start"></select>
```

Comment: You have already explained it: wrong selector `$('#start select')`. I'm just posting better version for select population, imho.